# linq - Best way to get records from linked table

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to entity framework and i have following database structure.

[image: db]

i'm trying to get relevant template for test.

what i have tried so far is as follows:

```
var val = context.TeamTest
     .Where(x => x.Tests_Id == 47)
     .Select(x => x.Team.Profile.ProfileSelections);
```

**Q1 :** why can't i get  `.Select(x => x.Team.Profile.ProfileSelections.Templates);`

I tried this way as well.

```
List<TeamTaskTemplate> templates = (from candidate in context.TeamTest
                                    join team in context.Teams  
                                    on candidate.Team_ID equals team.Team_ID
                                    join profile in context.Profiles
                                    on team.TeamTaskProfileID equals profile.TeamTaskProfileID
                                    join selectProf in context.ProfileSelections
                                    on profile.TeamTaskProfileID equals selectProf.TeamTaskProfileID
                                    join templ in context.Templates 
                                    on selectProf.TeamTaskTemplateID equals templ.TeamTaskTemplateID
                                    where candidate.Test_Id == 47
                                    select templ).ToList();
```

**Q2 :** What is the best way to get records from above 2 methods ?

**Q3** in general what is the best way to get records ? ( directly using context object as i mention 1 or use join queries mentioned in 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Q1: You should switch on LazyLoading:

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

And check that Team, Profile, ProfileSelections and Templates properties have virtual annotation.

Q2, Q3: First method is very simple and clear for understanding, but second one can be more effective.

Comment: if we enable it then will it take long time load data, if there's heavy data?

Comment: I think that not heavy, because you has specified condition: `Where(x => x.Tests_Id == 47)` at the beginning of your query that is why it will much reduce size of requested data.

Answer (score 1):

Q1 If you mapping be correctly [Info](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/796540/Relationship-in-Entity-Framework-Using-Code-First)

```
var val = context.TeamTest.Include("Team.Profile.ProfileSelection.Template")
     .Where(x => x.Tests_Id == 47).ToList();
```

For me this is the best way because get and set only the data that you needs

[Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)